# spring: add session attribute in every controller model

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, velocity

I want to add common used attribute in model for every controller.

Comment: And your question is? Any examples?

Comment: @home I found the solution, just misused #include and #parse. so i removed irreverent description and answered it below myself. thanks anyway.

Comment: How about using @SessionAttribute in a @ControllerAdvice?

Answer (score 1):

HandlerInterceptorAdapter can be used to intercept the request. For example, you can override preHandle to validate the session, and add the user to model in postHandle.

```
public class SessionValidator extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
}


@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
                       ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if (modelAndView != null) {
        modelAndView.getModelMap().addAttribute("user", session.getAttribute("user"));
    }
}

}
```